# How to fade input's ::placeholder with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

check both the HTML and the jQuery code below:

$(function(){

NOT WORKING:

```
`$(".c-button").click(function(){
    $("input.screen::placeholder").fadeOut(100).fadeIn();
});`
```

WORKING, BUT ITS THE WHOLE SCREEN THAT IS FADING. I ONLY WANTS THE ::placeholder-attr TO FADE:
/*

```
`$(".c-button").click(function(){
    $(".screen").fadeOut(100).fadeIn();
});`

*/
```

});

thanks.

Comment: `::placeholder` is a pseudo element, and as such, it is not in the DOM, and thus, not accessible to Javascript.

Comment: thanks @connexo.. do you know any other way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class changes done by jQuery and css styles based on the class. Perhaps this is more what you are looking for. For example:

```js
$(".c-button").click(function(){
    $("input.screen").toggleClass('active');
});

$("input.screen").on('focus' ,function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).on('blur', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
input.screen::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .1s ease;
}

input.screen.active::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .1s ease;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" class="screen" placeholder="Fill out">
    
    <p>
      <button class="c-button">Click me</button>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please note you might want to add more pseudo selectors in the css for browser compatibility https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Aplaceholder